# C++ delete segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
void EventCloseServer::act(){
    Server* serv = Program()::getServer();
    if (serv != NULL) {
        if (serv->running()) {
            serv->stop();
            serv->sync();
        }
        delete (serv);
    }
}
```

The problem arises when I execute this code twice. The first time, the function gets to `delete(serv)` alright. The second time, it causes segmentation fault before the call to `serv->running()` and after `serv != NULL`.
I don't understand why the second execution gets inside the first `if` statement. Isn't it true that the following will result in `myObject = NULL`?

```
Class* myObject = new Class();
/***/
delete(myObject); /* myObject = NULL ? */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not true.
`delete` does not set pointer to `NULL`. It merely deallocates the memory allocated to the pointer and calls appropriate destructors.

On other hand calling `delete` on a `NULL` pointer is a No-Op. So it is not required to check for `NULL` before calling `delete`.

Note that explicitly `NULL`ing the pointer after `delete` shall seem to solve your problem but it might hide problems in your code.The best way to solve this is to use Smart pointers and not raw pointers which need explicit memory management.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting `serv` needs to be set to `NULL`. Not the local variable, but the one which is returned by `Program()::getServer()`.

Assuming there is a `Program()::setServer`

```
delete(serv);
Program()::setServer(NULL);
```

Reusing a deleted pointer is recipe for a crash.
And deleting a pointer doesn't set it to `NULL`.